# How to filter on SSIS when querying from an Oracle source on the Oracle generic Date type

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I am trying to extract data from an Oracle Database using SSIS to a Microsoft Destination. I would like to filter the Extract on a generic Oracle date type of dd-mon-rr HH24:MI:SSXFF. When i run the query on SSIS the dates appear in the format MM/DD/YYYY. As a result I cannot get a result. Wonder if anyone can help me to filter it correctly.

```
SELECT CAST(GRA_DATE AS DATE) as GRA_DATE,
       CAST(VERIFIED_DATE AS DATE) as VERIFIED_DATE,
       VERIFIED_QTY,
       EXTRACT_DATE,
       SEQ_NBR
  FROM ORDERS
 WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(VERIFIED_DATE)), 'DD/MM/YYYY') =
       TO_DATE('07/08/2018', 'dd/MM/YYYY')
```

I expect retained data to be filtered to the 7th of August 2018.
Currently there is no result in SSIS but I get the result in the actual Oracle source

Comment: use `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(VERIFIED_DATE),'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY') = to_date('07/08/2018','dd/MM/YYYY')`

Answer (score 1):

seems `verified_date` is of date type( *`trunc` is being applied* ). So, extra conversion (*to char after to date*) is not needed.

Just query as

```
SELECT ....
  FROM ORDERS 
 WHERE trunc(verified_date) = date'2018-08-07'
```

where `date'YYYY-MM-DD'` conforms to `ISO 8601` standard.